# Shell Script needed - I have to collect time stamps from appserver logs

Tags: shell, logging

I have to collect time stamps from appserver logs and store it in an output file. Finally have to find the difference between each timestamps and print it. For example: If i have 10 timestapms collected and kept in a file. Have to find difference between 10th and 9th. 9th and 8th...........2nd and 1st timestamp. can anyone help me in writing shell scripting for this?

Comment: What do the timestamps look like?

Comment: What is the overall purpose? It sounds like you want to just record the timestamps and discard everything else - is that right? That doesn't sound like it would be very useful.

Comment: Time Stamp looks like this : "log:2011-04-12 06:49:02.874"

Comment: Log file : "App-10.log:2011-04-12 06:49:02.874 level=INFO thread=EJB-Timer-208971cf-98b7-4383-8a89-4aa843b263ec[target=jboss.j2ee:ear=ear-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=bam-4.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=BatchAcquisitionManagerImpl,service=EJB3] logger=com.intuit.cc.bam.BatchAcquisitionManagerImpl api= id= Executing work cycle.."

Answer (score 1):

To extract the timestamps and convert to an epoch time:

```
perl -MTime::Local -ne ' 
    ($ts, $y, $m, $d, $H, $M, $S, $frac) = 
        /((\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\.(\d+))/;
    $time = timelocal($S, $M, $H, $d, $m-1, $y-1900) + "0.$frac";
    print $ts, ",", $time, "\n";
' log.file > output.file
```

Given your input, this would output

```
2011-04-12 06:49:02.874,1302605342.874
```

To find the differences, you can now just do arithmetic on the time value in the last column.